# Make systemd service conditional of available disk space

Tags: systemd

Am migrating my upstart mysql init script that checks whether there is >100MB diskspace availabe, if not, sleep 10 seconds and try again.

I can implement it in systemd like this, but it hurts my eyes.

```
[Service]
RestartSec=10
Restart=on-failure
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/test $(($(/usr/bin/stat -f --format="%a*%S/1024/1024" /data))) -gt 100 || (echo Less than 100MB available on /data; /bin/false)'
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld
TimeoutSec=300
```

Is there a cleaner solution? Possibly one where mysql is stopped when the available disk space drops below a certain threshold. Could I make a dummy unit and include it with [Requires](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Requires=) ? Akin to Upstart's `start on starting mysql`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do is to move the long line of bash into its own file and have `ExecStartPre=` call that file.

There is no built-in `system` feature or directive to conditionally start a service based on how much disk space is available.

Comment: And would you recommend to make a dummy "disk space" unit and include it as a Requires ?

Comment: Using `Requires=` for a disk space checker seems overly complicated. I like the simple `ExecStartPre=` solution. `Requires` is designed for other persistent running services, which your disk space test is not. `Requires=` also implies an inverse relationship on shutdown, which also does not apply here.